# Windows Docker swarm overlay networking

Tags: windows, docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, windows-networking

I set up the Windows Server: docker Swarm and created one attachable **overlay network**. However, communication between containers in different servers is not happening.

If I add a Linux server to the Swarm overlay network, I can reach the Windows server container IP from the Linux server container but vice versa not happening.

> Please clarify why it is not happening in Windows Server containers.

For Windows Server, network drivers like Transparent, Bridge, and L2Bridge are created as local network.
Which one supports multi-node container communication in windows server?

I set up the Windows Server Swarm and created one attachable overlay network. However, communication between containers in different servers is not happening.

If I add a Linux server to the Swarm overlay network, I can reach the Windows server container IP from the Linux server container but vice versa not happening.
Please clarify why it is not happening in Windows Server containers.

For Windows Server, network drivers like Transparent, Bridge, and L2Bridge are created as local network.
Which one supports multi-node container communication in windows server